# What Java Date Format to correctly parse?

Tags: java, date

I have some code like the following:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
...

this.timestampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(timestampFormat, Locale.UK);
this.timestampFormat.parse(modifyTimestamp.get().toString());
```

But the parsing throws an error:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20150429142243.925Z"
```

I tried both these date format strings:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'
yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'
```

The "925Z" part of the time I think is the problem.
Should the second date format string be correct in this case, although it isn't working.

Comment: It seems that your `timestampFormat` value is not compatible with date string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS'Z'", Locale.UK);
```

925 is the millisecond, so you need `SSS` to represent that as well.

Comment: Check this for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone

Comment: No need for the `Locale` in this case. Only needed if parsing name of day or month and such. With only digits, and the ordering known, no need for Locale.

Answer (score 4):

You input String also has [milliseconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS'Z'", Locale.UK);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Similar to accepted correct answer, but using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```
String input = "20150429142243.925Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern ( "yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSZ" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime ( input ).withZone ( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

## Locale Not Needed

No need for the [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) in this case. Only needed if parsing name of day or month and such. With only digits, and the ordering known, no need for Locale.

Do not [confuse Locale for time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32162108/642706). They are orthogonal issues. If you want a [UK time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom), apply it explicitly using a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (never the 3 or 4 letter codes).

Example code, again using Joda-Time 2.8.

```
dateTimeEuropeLondon = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

If your string had a `T` between the date portion and the time-of-day portion, it would comply with the basic formats defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The you could use one of the ISO-compliant formatters built into Joda-Time rather than specify the pattern explicitly.

```
String input = "20150429T142243.925Z";  // "T" separator inserted in middle.
DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormatter.basicDateTime().parseDateTime ( input ).withZone ( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later come bundled with the successor to Joda-Time, the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)).

Unlike Joda-Time, the java.time pre-defined formatters have no ["basic" version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles) omitting the HYPHEN-MINUS and COLON characters. So we must explicitly define the pattern for the formatter.

```
String input = "20150429142243.925Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSX" ).withZone( ZoneOffset.UTC );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zdt : " + zdt );
```

When run.

> zdt : 2015-04-29T14:22:43.925Z